# python alias in ~/.zshrc overrides virtual environment source

Tags: python, bash, python-venv

I've got a couple aliases setup in my terminal session initialization shell script ~/.zshrc

```
alias python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9
alias pip=/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3.9
```

These are interfering with my virtual environment workflow:

```
>>> cd my_project
>>> python -m venv venv
>>> source venv/bin/activate
>>> which python
python: aliased to /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9
```

You can see how the virtual environment was not activated. Any suggestions on how I can work with `venv` while having these aliases setup in my ~/.zshrc?

Comment: I'd just rename the aliases, to e.g. `py39` and `pip39`.

Comment: Perhaps consider using `pyenv`, if you have multiple Python installations that you want to use (or even just one that isn't the system Python, but that you generally want to use).

Comment: Could you put `unalias python pip` in `venv/bin/activate`? I don't use Zsh myself so I'm not sure.

Comment: Instead of using aliases, put a symlink somewhere on $PATH.  Virtualenv activation prepends path, so it will win.

Comment: These are all good ideas. Running `unalias python pip && source venv/bin/activate` does the trick. The trouble is that my IDE (vscode) won't do that. Renaming the aliases was what I was trying to avoid but I may do that. Have heard good things about `pyenv` for handling python on mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a directory `~/bin`. In that directory create two links:

```
ln -vs /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9 ~/bin/python
ln -vs /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3.9 ~/bin/pip
```

Edit your `.zshrs` to include:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

The links will hide the normal executables. When virtualenv will be activated, the links will be hiden by the PATH set up by virtualenv.

Comment: This is working, and seems to do exactly what I want!

Comment: I like this solution, but running `python -m venv venv` says `The system cannot find the file specified`. How can I fix it? Edit: I am using .bashrc instead of .zshrs.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your alias:

```
python = "python3.9"
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on my machine `python3` and `pip3` commands always point to the right directory when venv is activated or deactivated. If this is the case on your machine use it to alias.

```bash
alias python='eval $(which python3)'
alias pip='eval $(which pip3)'
```

Updates the `python` and `pip` aliases when using virtual environments.